# Push repo state to remote without a file

Tags: git, github

My team is working with two remotes: `origin` and `backup`.

`backup` is GitHub-based, so it does not support large files. Someone made a commit to `origin` with a large file and since then we have all made numerous commits.

**We have since deleted that large file.** (In fact, I didn't finish `pull`ing the commit with it and I don't think I actually downloaded it because  it was removed in the succeeding commit.)

I have tried

```
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan tmp
git commit -m "Root"
git push backup master
```

but the `push` fails due to that large file exceeding the size limit.

**How do I push the current state of `origin` to `backup` but not the large file?**

Answer (score 0):

> *backup is GitHub-based, so it does not support large files. Someone made a commit to origin with a large file and since then we have all made numerous commits.*
>
> *We have since deleted that large file.*

If you ran `git rm` on it, you didn't. Git stores a complete chain of all files in each commit. When you `git rm` a file, it's still in history. It's still in the repository. You'd have to completely obliterate it from history. Simplest way to do that is using the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

But there's a better way to handle the large file problem: allow them.

Use [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to handle large files. This only stores a pointer to the large file in the repository. The actual file is stored elsewhere. Then you can put all the large files in your repository you want.

There's still the problem of what to do with that large file that's already been committed. BFG to the rescue again! You can [use the BFG to retroactively place large files into `git-lfs`](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5).

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --convert-to-git-lfs 'large_file_name' --no-blob-protection
```

Then continue as normal.